# Laravel model.save() dying silently without exception

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel but have worked with ORMs in other languages.
The save method on one of the newly created table is failing.
There is no exception & I know that it fails because the echo after the save doesn't show.
The laravel log in **../app/storage/logs/laravel.log** is empty (has never shown anything even in case of errors).
How do I find what's going wrong ?

```
            try
            {
                $p1 = $this->postsSharedWithMe->newInstance();
                $p1->shared_with_user_id = $sharedID;
                $p1->post_id = $post->id;
                echo '$p1->shared_with_user_id : ', $p1->shared_with_user_id, '<br></br>';
                echo '$p1->post_id : ', $p1->post_id, '<br></br>';
                echo 'Now saving : ', $sharedID, '<br></br>';
                $r1 = $p1->save();
                echo 'Result of saving : ', $r1, '<br></br>'; // *** THIS NEVER PRINTS
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                // THIS EXCEPTION NEVER PRINTS EITHER
                echo '**** Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "<br></br>";
            }
```

No code after the try/catch executes, hence it's failing for sure.
The model is very simple :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laracasts\Presenter\PresentableTrait;

/**
*
*@author : xxxx
*/
class PostsSharedWithMe extends Model
{
    use PresentableTrait;

    protected $table = "posts_shared_with";

    protected $presenter = "App\\Presenters\\PostsSharedWithPresenter";

    public function fromPost()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\\Models\\Post', 'post_id');
    }

    public function fromUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\\Models\\User', 'shared_with_user_id');
    }
}
```

Adding a dump of the **var_dump($p1)**

```
object(App\Models\PostsSharedWithMe)[1085]
  protected 'table' => string 'posts_shared_with' (length=17)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'shared_with_user_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'post_id' => int 46
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'morphClass' => null
  public 'exists' => boolean false
  protected 'softDelete' => boolean false
```

Comment: Just to see if I get an exception, I changed $p1->save() to $p1->saveXYZ() and interestingly I haven't got any exception on this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options to do when method save() is not working:

- enable debug mode (if it's not enabled already)
- check your migration for that table and check table name in the model
- check variable names and column names if there are no extra settings

Answer (score 1):

You are using `p1.save()` and it should be `p1->save()`.

Comment: I just realized and changed it to that, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Also, please notice that you are using commas instead of periods to concatenate.

Comment: I went and checked inside Model.php and the $query is empty in "$saved = $this->performInsert($query);" When I created the new table, did I miss doing something ?

Comment: @PlanetUnknown: Post a var_dump($p1). You should have defined shared_with_user_id and post_id in your PostsSharedWithMe model. Also, you must have a migration with variables from your model otherwise save() won't work.

Comment: @drive235 Added the var_dump($p1). I haven't done any migrations yet, since retrieving data worked. I'm using an existing project and just learning laravel, hence not sure how migrations "with variables" work.

Comment: @PlanetUnknown: I assumed that that you were missing a migration (which creates table) with the same column names and variable names from the model. Debug mode or any error reporting is active?

Comment: @drive235 C:\wamp\www\reco\local\app\config\app.php has 'debug' => true, but the storage\logs\laravel.log is empty. Since this is windows, the access is already present for everyone. And I created the table manuall - seems I shouldn't have done that..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem: I would save a new model and it would store, but not return.

My problem: I had a Model Observer with a Created method. This method was updating a calculated value and trying save again. I